# Logistic regression not converging in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, mnist

I am trying to fit a binary logistic model using  MNIST data using glm function. I am getting an error "Failed to converge". should apply any transformations before I fit the model?

Here is the link for my dataset
[MNIST DATASET](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TXcFkg-tngMEMqJAvniwsdQXZRoGGiEy/view)

```
 df<-read.csv('mnist_train.csv')
#assigning column names
names(df)<-c(1:785)

#Relabeld the data with values
#If the digit is 9 then its labeled as 1 else its labled as 0
df$`1`<-factor(df$`1`,levels=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),labels=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1))

#Removed null values
cldf<-df[complete.cases(df),]

#fitting model
model<-glm(cldf$`1`~.,family =binomial(link = "logit"),data=cldf)
summary(model)
```

I read the following references but solution provided is not my case as I am using 0 and 1 as labels.
[Logistic Regression implementation with MNIST - not converging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954289/logistic-regression-implementation-with-mnist-not-converging)
Below are the warning messages I got:

1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Any directions would be appreciated.

Comment: try googling "complete separation logistic regression" ...

Comment: We'd need to see a representative sample of data to know why. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)